# Binary search tree operator overloading []

Tags: binary-search-tree

Whenever i try to test the function I always get the value of the root and I dont know what's wrong with it.

```
Data& operator[] (int k) {
            if(n==0) return root->value;
            Node * temp= helperOper(root, n);
            return temp->value;
}

        Node * helperOper(Node * T, int& n) const{
            if(T!=nil){
                n--;
                if(n==0) helperOper(T->left, n);
                n--;
                if (n==0) helperOper(T->right, n);
                //n--;
                return T;
            }
            return nil;
        }

int main(){
        BST<int> x;
        x.insert(1);
        x.insert(2);
        x.insert(3);
        cout << temp[2];
}
```

Comment: Please post the full code, and how you're running it. I assume this is C++?

Comment: yes, and i keep getting 1

Comment: This isn't the full code yet?